# « Prémédités » ou « calculés » ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dans la série « Parfaite », série qui met en scène un homme aux prises avec des problèmes psychiatriques rappelant ceux qui caractérisent plusieurs troubles à la fois, tous les faits et gestes du personnage principal sont

…**prémédités** et rien n’est laissé au hasard, allant des objets qu’il fera tomber pour attirer l’attention de l’élue de son coeur -celle de qui il sera épris et follement amoureux d’emblée -en passant par la façon dont il la regardera, jusqu’aux mots qu’il emploiera pour se lier d’amitié avec elle.

…**calculés** et rien n’est laissé au hasard, allant des objets qu’il fera tomber pour attirer l’attention de l’élue de son coeur -celle de qui il sera épris et follement amoureux d’emblée- en passant par la façon font il la regardera, jusqu’aux mots qu’il emploiera pour la séduire et se lier d’amitié avec elle.

Si l’on se rapporte au paragraphe que j’ai écrit dans les détails, serait-ce préférable d’employer le verbe « préméditer » ou « calculer », sinon un autre verbe?

Vous pouvez, si vous le souhaitez, me proposer d’autres tournures. Merci!

Comment: — *Prémédité* (« Décider, préparer avec calcul » dixit le Robert, synonyme de *projeter* : *pro-jeter* = *lancer* et *projet-er* = *envisager, préparer*) implique une intention réfléchie avant de réaliser l'action pour atteindre le but, synonyme d'usage induisant une intention cachée  [souvent illicite ou néfaste] : *combiner*  —  *calculé* se réfère à la méthode utilisée pour réaliser une expérience, est induit dans préméditer/combiner, est synonyme de *apprécier, estimer, supputer* (ce dernier est sujet de suspicion = défiance, méfiance -même source). *Envisagé* dénote une intention aimable.

Comment: Ca peut être aussi *prevus* ou **planifiés* ? A mon avis, *prémédités* a l'air negatif, car utilisé beaucoup dans le contexte criminel (mais peut-être ce mot paraît neutre aux francophones.)